# Iterate through files in directory and count frequency of string

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a Perl program that will iterate through all files in a given directory and identify the number of times a specific string is present in each of the files.

It's combing through DNA sequences looking for the frequency of `ATG` on the forward strand or reverse complement depending on the direction of the sequence I have. I know that all the sequences contain at least one ATG or CAT (reverse complement to ATG) and for some many more but in my output file it's giving me zero or one. Any suggestions?

P.S. Ignore the unnecessary variables I'm editing a previously written script

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @file=<*.fasta>;
for $file (@file) {


my $get_file = <../[ES]RR*/> or print "Could not find";
$check = substr($file, 0, 9);
$filename = substr ($get_file, 3, 20);




my $pattern_reverse = 'CCATTTTGTCCAA[AC]C';
my $pattern = 'G[GT]TTGGACAAAATGG';
my $forward_start = 'ATG' ;
my $reverse_start = 'CAT' ;

open(DATA,$file) or die ("Couldn't open file.");

my $contig_name;
my $not_found_mark;
my $position;
my $symbol = ">";
my $contig_string;
my $contig_length;

$contig_name = <DATA>;
$not_found_mark = 1;
$contig_string = "";

while ((my $line = <DATA>) && ($not_found_mark)) {

chop($line);

$position = index($line,$symbol);
if ($position < 0) {
        $contig_string .= $line;
        }
else {
        $not_found_mark = 0;
        }
}


print "$filename \n";
$contig_length = length $contig_string;
print "The contig is $contig_length characters. \n";



if ($contig_string =~ /($pattern)/ ) {
        print "Found forward pattern.\n";
        if ( $contig_string =~ /(ATG)/ ) {
            $ATG_count = 0;
            $ATG_count++;
            open ( Match, ">>", ATG_match ) or die "Could not open ATG_match";
            print Match ">$filename $check $ATG_count \n" 
                or die "Could not append.";
            print "$ATG_count \n";

        }
}

elsif ( $contig_string =~ /($pattern_reverse)/ ) {
        print "Found reverse pattern.\n";
        if ( $contig_string =~ /(CAT)/ ) {
            $ATG_count = 0;
            $ATG_count++;
            open ( Match, ">>", ATG_match ) or die "Could not open ATG_match";
            print Match ">$filename $check $ATG_count \n" 
                or die "Could not append.";
            print "$ATG_count \n";
    }
}

else  {
        print "$file \n";
        print "Did not find pattern. \n";
        open ( Nomatch, ">>", no_ATG_match ) or die "Could not open";
        print Nomatch ">$filename $check\n" or die "Could not append";      
        }
}
print ( "There are $ATG_count ATG's \n" );
close ( Match );
close ( Nomatch );
close( DATA );
```

Comment: @Borodin While I appreciate the advice and edits do you have any suggestions with respect to my script not finding the ATG string within my sequence

Comment: I tidied your code in an attempt to understand what it was doing. I'm afraid it still isn't clear, and the volume of irrelevant code and variable declarations obfuscates it even more

Comment: @Borodin I removed all the irrelevant code. The output I want in a new file is the name of the sequences, the name check, and the number of ATG's. I am getting only 1 ATG for all the sequences but I am sure that there are many more.

Comment: I assume there are multiple FASTA files, multiple sequences in each, and multiple occurrences of `CAT`/`ATG` in each sequence? Your code processes all the files, but only counts the first occurrence of `CAT`/`ATG` in the first sequence.

Comment: Yes it's multiple FASTA files of contigs constructed from the same reads and each has multiple ATG/CAT. What must be changed so that it searches the entire sequence of the first FASTA file and counts the ATG/CAT?

Comment: Just one sequence per file?

Comment: Okay, but your code looks for lines containing `$symbol`, which is `>` and can only appear at the start of a new sequence. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes the ">" denotes the start of a new sequence. I am interested only in the first sequence of each file. The following sequences are shorter sequences.

Comment: I was thinking if there was a way for me to make sure it only iterated through the first FASTA file within each file I could change my loop too

Comment: *so that it matches globally because currently it iterates through all the fasta files and counts the first occurrence of ATG

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions?

It looks like you are setting your count to be 1 all the time with these two lines.

```
$ATG_count = 0;
$ATG_count++;
```

Given you're using `++`, I'm guessing that's not what you need to do

Declaring `my $ATG_count = 0;` near the top of your script is what you need to initialise it, thereafter, just increment with `++`. (While you're at it, is there any reason you're not beginning `use strict; use warnings`?)

You say that

> I'm editing a previously written script

Why? This appears to be a simple task and it would be much easier to start again and write code which does what you want and which you understand than try to make code which does something else to do what you want.

Comment: I wrote the previous script and it's important because DNA does not have direction. The parts of the script that I have kept are important in order for me to know that the ATG is a start codon and not just an ATG for a sequence on the reverse complement strand.

Comment: I also tried to declare `my $ATG_code = 0` near the top of the script and it produced the same output. Each file has multiple FASTA files within them that are different constructs of the same sequence. I am interested in only the first construct. Is there a way I could have my script search globally for the ATG string but only within the first FASTA file?

Answer (score -1):

To count the occurrence of a string you can search for a match put the matches in list context and then assign them to a string to get counts:

$foo = () = $string =~ /regex/;